# testing with iOS simulator for international users

Tags: ios, internationalization, keyboard, numbers, ios-simulator

a noob question here.

I have an app that does number calculations. I support different foreign languages and try to test them in the iOS simulator as much as I can.

recently I got a bad review from a Korean user where the complaint seems to be something to the extent of "getting only input errors ... something ... floating point ... something". The online translation does not work that well.

now, my app checks the input entered by the user and displays "input error" message when it detects characters that are not valid for that particular input field. I check the asc value of each character entered. maybe this is part for the problem. but on the other hand isn't asc 48 number zero in ANY input language ?

so my question is ... if I setup the iOS simulator to (let's say) Korean language, test my application (enter numbers, make calculation, etc) and it (seemingly) works just fine ... what's out there "in the real Korean world" that my application might not be agreeing with ... or that I am unable to test/simulate with the iOS simulator.

sigh! I wish there was a way to communicate with people that leave reviews ... it would make life so much easier.

Comment: What keyboard style are you using in your app? Numberpad only?

Comment: no, Numbers and Punctuations. Some of my input fields work with special characters, but most of the input fields are for numbers only. I was thinking about going Numberpad only, but then there is the missing decimal point.

Comment: On Japanese keyboards it is possible to enter non-ASCII numbers, but it doesn't seem to be the case with the Korean keyboard. It is possible I suppose that his errors could have nothing to do with the language and everything to do with a real bug in your app. Seems like a tough thing to track down either way.

Comment: yeah, that's why it's so frustrating not being able to ask the person a follow up question ... "hey, what/where you entered when you got the error ?" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about setting your device to Korean for testing?

Comment: yes I did that too, everything seems to work the same way (fine) as in the iOS simulator. I was thinking there might be something different on the actual Korean phone, or maybe there are some special add-ons/settings/keyboards etc they use that would cause something other that the regular asc values to be entered by the international users

Comment: Are you validating your input? Perhaps the solution is to simply aggressively validate what users can input if you can't manage to reproduce the error itself.

Comment: yeah, I will have to add a few more checks for sure. can't expect the users to behave, right ? :)

Answer (score 0):

YOU could just make sure the number is output out as a number and not some random string. Try this code.

```
textfieldNumber = Int(textfield.value)
```